# Apollo @connection directive in writeQuery doesn't clear paginated list

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I have a GET_NOTIFICATIONS query that fetches a paginated list of notifications; I wish to clear the entire list in cache (currently trying to use the @connection directive in the update function of a mutation to achieve this).

The GET_NOTIFICATIONS query:

```
query GetNotifications($offset: Int!, $limit: Int!) {
    getNotifications(offset: $offset, limit: $limit) 
    @connection(key: "notif") {
      id
      title
      body
      read
      link
      image {
        id
        url
      }
    }
  }
```

The button onPress() handler triggering the DELETE_ALL mutation:

```
onPress={() => {
  deleteAllNotif({
    update: cache => {
      cache.writeQuery({
          query: GET_NOTIFICATIONS,
          data: {
              getNotifications: []
          }
      });
    }
  });
}}
```

The above code doesn't seem to delete clear getNotifications in cache. Am I misunderstanding something? Is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Have you tried to precise the variables in your writeQuery ?

Comment: It shouldn't need the variables based on the official docs; the @connection directive should enable us to cache the paginated list results under the "notif" key as above and allow us to writeQuery without passing in any variables.

Comment: Probably, it doesn't clear the cache because it needs the variables for precision